# How configure different subdomains on firebase hosting for to serve different content by each subdomain?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Can i create different subdomains from Google Domains, register them on Firebase Hosting and serve different content by from each one subdomains?

If the answer is yes, how?
I followed this guide: https://medium.com/@fransandi/use-firebase-multisite-hosting-to-associate-multiple-domains-subdomains-to-your-project-ee099109bfe9 and although its title says "multiple domains/**subdomains**", it didn't help me for deployed content on my subdomains. Always got this error: "Error: HTTP Error: 404, Requested entity was not found" when run "firebase deploy --only hosting:my-target".
Deploy in my main domain easy, but for subdomains... I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate folder for each site/app, and then deploy hosting for each site/app. When you click the "add custom domain" button, type in the subdomain that you want to use. Example

> mysubdomain.mydomain.com

When you add the 2 A records to your domain registrar make the host name your subdomain instead of @ or www.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try.

Comment: Your welcome. Let me know what happens. Remember that domain changes can take up to 72 hours to propagate.